# Find the number of non-negative integer solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 57$ where $x_1 \lt 3, x_3 \ge 4$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the number of non-negative integers to 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 57$$ where $$x_1 \lt 3, x_3 \ge 4$$
I first found the total number of solutions N=$57+6-1\choose57$=6471002, then the total number of equations for the restriction $x_1 \ge 3$, N(P1)=$54+6-1\choose54$=3425422, then for the restriction $x_3 \le 3$, N(P2)=$4+6-1\choose4$=126 and I have to find the number of solutions for both the restrictions N(P1P2), but I don't know the number I should plug in the combination formula or if my calculations are correct.

Comment: The way you handled the $x_1\geq 3$ restriction you can also handle the $x_3\geq 3$ restriction. Which is to say, remove the restriction and say you want $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6 = 54$ instead. That's one less thing to worry about.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: How did you get $54+6-1\choose54$? That's really all there is to it. Just do it to $x_3$ rather than $x_1$, and simplify the problem _before_ trying to use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: I see now that we have $x_3\geq 4$ rather than $x_3 \geq 3$. So apologies for the confusion there. Still, that's something I would suggest you take care of first, and _then_ set to find the number of solutions. Like was suggested in the naswer below.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is equivalent to distribute $57$ candies to $6$ kids. To eliminate $x_3\ge4$ restriction, let's give $4$ candies to $x_3$. So problem is now

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 53$ with $x_1\le2$

I prefer Stars and Bars method [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

$x_1=0:\quad$ $ x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 53$. This implies we have $53$ stars and $4$ bars and we use Permutations with Repetition [see here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations-with-repetition/)

$$\frac{57!}{53!4!}$$

$x_1=1:\quad$ $ x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 52$
$$\frac{56!}{52!4!}$$

$x_1=2:\quad$ $ x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 51$

$$\frac{55!}{51!4!}$$

So the answer is $$\frac{57!}{53!4!}+\frac{56!}{52!4!}+\frac{55!}{51!4!}$$

Comment: How did you get x1≤2?

Comment: Because $x_1<3$ and it is non-negative integer, $x_1<3\equiv 0\le x_1\le2$

Comment: This is a [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.

Answer (score 0):

First eliminate the lower bound
x3>=4 ..lets take x3-4>=0 take x3-4 = y
so our equation gets reduced to
x1+x2+y3+x4+x5+x6=57-4=53
NO of solution of this equation can be obtained from stars and bars concept.
divide 53 identical balls in 6 distinct boxes.

C(53+6-1,6-1) = 58!/53!5! = 4582116

Now we have to eliminate all those cases where x1>=3

take y1=x1-3>=0
our equation gets reduced to

y1+x2+y3+x4+x5+x6=53-3=50

solution of this equation is

C(50+6-1,6-1) = 55!/5!50!=3478761.

We need to remove these solutions to satisfy our equation

Total number of solutions = 4582116-3478761= 1103355

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).